# Do not print a variable used in the query

Tags: web, printing, rdf, sparql, resultset

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT ?names ?country ?city
WHERE {
  ...
}
```

However my hw says to print only the names and the city, not the country. How can ask SPARQL not to include `?country` in the result set?

If it can't be done, I would like to know of course, so that I can stop searching Google.

Comment: And you couldn't find the answer by using Google or reading the W3C specs or any simple SPARQL tutorial?i

Comment: @AKSW no! As you saw in my question, I was searching Google...I didn't try the specs I admit. That's why you downvoted?

Comment: Just asking @AKSW, I would just like to know why I got the downvotes, that's all.

Comment: I assume this got downvoted because on the face of it, this is something you could have figured out yourself with minimal effort. Any basic SPARQL tutorial (and there quite a few of those available) will tell you how the SELECT clause works (and to be frank, it's actually pretty damn obvious even _without_ a tutorial). YMMV of course.

Comment: I see @JeenBroekstra. Well I searched before posting. Am not yet at the point of that being obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the `?country` from your query, to prevent it from printed out:

```
SELECT ?names ?city

WHERE {   
  ...   
}
```